# Создание объекта определенного типа во время выполнения с++

Tags: c++, типы-данных

Возможно ли во время выполнения получить информацию о типе объекта, а затем создать объект данного типа?
Т.е. что-то наподобие:

```
string type;
cin >> type; // ввод типа пользователем
SETTYPE(type) obj; // SETTYPE должна установить тип
//... использование obj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так - нельзя.

Можно, например, создать переменную того же типа, что и другая переменная:

```
string s;

...

decltype(s) str;
```

Так, как вы написали - можно поиграться и получить объект-наследник, в зависимости от значения - что-то типа

```
class Base { ... virtual ~Base(){} };
class D1: public Base ...
class D2: public Base ...
...

Base * makeD(int i)
{
    if (i == 1) return new D1;
    if (i == 2) return new D2;
    ...
```

Ну, в общем, как-то так...

Но вот в общем виде вычислить тип полностью во время выполнения - не тот это язык.

А где и зачем это вам нужно? Не вопрос ли это о том, какой рукой держать микроскоп для забивания гвоздей? :) В смысле, может, то, что вы хотите, решаемо иначе?

Comment: этот вопрос связан с попытками разобраться в шаблонах :) У меня было ошибочное представление, что заранее  компилятор не может  создать код для шаблонной функции.
 Сейчас мне стало ясно: какие бы аргументы не передавались в шаблонную функцию, их тип будет известен на этапе компиляции => создание кода для конкретного экземпляра происходит на этапе компиляции

Comment: Именно. Тогда вопрос о том, зачем, снят :)